# Mysql - Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1 (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE T2 (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RecordID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  KEY `RecordID` (`RecordID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

where T1 has ~100,000 records
and T2 has ~6,000,000 records

The following query takes ~1.5 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.RecordID
```

when I add the following where clause, it takes ~20 seconds:

```
WHERE T1.Date <= '2017-02-18'
```

Knowing that the query with the where cause returns no records.

I need your help please.

Comment: Consider adding index on the `Date` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful when you measure the speed of a query.  If you only look for the return of the first row, then you might get a misleading indicator.

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN
     T2 
     ON T1.ID = T2.RecordID
WHERE T1.Date <= '2017-02-18';
```

You want a composite index on `T1(Date, ID)`.  You also want an index on `T2(RecordId)`, but you already have that index.